# Arrange datetimevalue not working (main purpose is to sorting the date by date value)

Tags: python, datetime

arrange datetimevalue not working (main purpose is to sorting the date by date value)

*I'm praticing not to use building function `sorted`  , but write one myself, when doing the comparing is fine, but sort is not work*

the error code:

```js
import datetime
list1 = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04']

list1 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in list1] 
  
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    i =0
    if list1[i]>list1[i+1]:
        list1[i],list1[i+1]=list1[i+1],list1[i]

print (list1)
print (type(list1))
```

[image: (pic) under line is not what I want]
I want the output be :

```
[ '2011-02-04','2011-06-02', '2011-08-05']
```

*(2 version code) working for printing out the datetime format*

```js
import datetime
def date_sorting_operation(input_list):
  
  list1_date = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in input_list] 
  for i in range(len(list1_date)):
        for i in range(len(list1_date) - 1):
            if list1_date[i] > list1_date[i + 1]:
              temporary = list1_date[i + 1]
              list1_date[i + 1] = list1_date[i]
              list1_date[i] = temporary
            
  #list1_date_string = [datetime.strftime(fs, "%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M") for fs in list1_date] 
  return list1_date
                     
customer_date_list = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-01-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-01-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-02-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']
print (date_sorting_operation(customer_date_list))
```

Comment: You are basically not looping through, by setting  value of i=0 at starting of every iteration. And how do you expect this sort to work with a single pass on the array ?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use built-in `sorted` with `strptime` as key:

```
from datetime import datetime

list1 = ['2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04']
sorted(list1, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Output:

```
['2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05']
```

Comment: I'm praticing not to use building function `sorted ` , but write one myself, when doing the comparing is fine, but sort is not work